# Scripts from Wordpress child theme not enqueing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been unable to get my custom scripts from a child theme I made show up.
I've added my child theme and appropriate style.css and functions.php files, among others. Followed the usual set up instructions.

Then, I've added custom javascript inside
child_theme_directory/js/custom.js

which in my specific case worked out to be
TWR/js/twr-js.js

I attempted to follow various tutorials and added code to my functions.php in attempt to enqueue those js scripts, such as:

```
function load_twr_script() {
    wp_register_script ( 'twr-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/twr-js.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twr-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/twr-js.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_twr_script');
```

and

```
function load_twr_script(){
    wp_register_script ( 'twr-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/twr-js.js', array('divi-custom-script'), '1.1', true );
    $twr_data = array(
        'home_url' => esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )
    );
    wp_localize_script ('twr-js', "twr_data", $twr_data );
    wp_enqueue_script ('twr-js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_twr_script');
```

and a few other attempts. But my js script isn't even showing up under sources in inspector. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is almost guaranteed that the script is not at the URL you've defined.  Do a `var_dump(get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/twr-js.js');` - what do you get? Also, try removing the dependencies and see if it loads without them.

Comment: You're right, `var_dump(get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/twr-js.js');` shows the wrong URL (of parent theme not child theme.)
However, using `var_dump(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/twr-js.js'` gives the right URL

Comment: Hey caleb, using var_dump was a great idea because I've replaced all the get_template_directory_uri with get_stylesheet_directory_uri which helped me find one that works. Thanks!